# Accessing hidden field value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, hidden-field

I have a hidden field in my form, I'm setting the hidden field's value on the server and trying to access this value from javascript,

I get the error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined

If I view the source the hidden field value is set and the ID of the hidden field is the same as the ID I'm calling.

ASPX

```
            var v = document.getElementById('hxValue').value;
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hxValue" runat="server"/>
```

VB

```
            hxValue.Value = "Value1"
```

I recall doing this before and it should be relatively simple but for some reason, i'm not getting it right.

Answer (score 5):

Your code will work. For simple forms, just add

```
<asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="static" ID="hxValue" runat="server"/>
```

OR

you need to find the client id using

```
'<%=hxValue.ClientID%>'
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok it appears my hidden field's value had not been set before the script had run, therefore receiving a null value. I had assumed that placing breakpoints on the server page load and the script would establish if the control was being set before the script ran, appears not.

Fixed as below:

```
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
            <head>

            <title></title>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function GetHiddenValues() {
                    var v = document.getElementById('<%= hxValue.ClientID %>').value;
                }
            </script>
            </head>

            <body onload="GetHiddenValues() ;">

            <form runat="server">

            <asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="static" ID="hxValue" runat="server"/>

            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: Thanks this works. No need to run in the onload, just in case that confuses anybody.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `innerText` not `value` to retrieve the value of hxValue.

```
var v = document.getElementById('hxValue').innerText
```

If you were using `jQuery` you could also do

```
var v = $("#hxValue").val();
```

Comment: I tried innerText but getting - Unable to get value of the property 'innerText': object is null or undefined @Darren Davies

Comment: The ID may not actually be called hxValue on the client as ASP.NET may add it's own prefix. Try: document.getElementById('<%= hxValue.ClientID %>').value; as yogi suggests.

Comment: Because of concept of controls that classic ASP.NET uses, control IDs in generated HTML are not the ones you use at server side (ASP.NET allows multiple elements with same ID on a page, but single one within one parent element)

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević but surely when I view the source at runtime the ID of the control reflected is the ID that has been assigned to it?

Comment: ID which you see in rendered HTML is the ID you want. ID which you see in Visual Studio while debugging is not the same. In Visual Studio debugger, you should be looking at [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In .NET 4, [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) was introduced to allow more predictable generation of IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the Info @NikolaRadosavljević I was accessing the right ID, though my control was not being set before the script had run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var v = document.getElementById('<%= hxValue.ClientID %>').value;
```

Problem is that Hidden Field is server side control and it's ID that you have given is a server side ID, you will have to get client side ID of that control to refer it in your client side JavaScript or Jquery.

**Update**

put this script at the end of your page, just before `</body>` something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  var v = document.getElementById('<%= hxValue.ClientID %>').value;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok I've tried getting the clientside ID of control as above but still unable to get the value, I'm getting the object is null or undefined.

Comment: please access after page load completed using Jquery Ready method var v = document.getElementById('<%= hxValue.ClientID %>').value;

Answer (score 0):

Try `<asp:HiddenField ID="hxValue" runat="server" Value=""/>`
Then call it by id and set value