# Unable to access hidden HTML elements from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my code, I have a simple field as below

```
<input ID="lblDocumentPath" Class="DefaultButtons" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"></input>
```

When I set the visible property to true, the element is loaded properly and JS is able to read it.

```
document.getElementById(filePathLabel).value = arrRowsArray[1];
```

But, with property set to false, JS can't find the element. If I open the DOM explorer in IE, all I see is an empty input field.

```
</input><//input>
```

Not sure, what I am doing wrong here. Kindly let me know what stupid mistake I am overlooking.

Edit:

I think I am going crazy. I am not sure, what I am doing anymore. Anyway, this is what I normally do. [Accessing hidden field value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579995/accessing-hidden-field-value-in-javascript)

Simple stuff, right. But apparently my code behind can't find the damn field at all. It just keep saying, "lblDocumentPath does not exist in current context.

I have spent 3 hours, trying to pass one hidden field to code behind. :(

Answer (score 1):

When server side field is rendered, its client id changes. Use the below code to access the field in javascript but it will work if your javascript code is in the same .aspx or .asmx file-

```
document.getElementById("<%=lblDocumentPath.ClientID %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

**JS Solution:**

The proper way to use hidden input fields as follows:

```
<input id="lblDocumentPath" type="hidden"></input>
```

By following this format, you can still access the hidden field as follows:

```
document.getElementById("lblDocumentPath");
```

See more: [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j1w26new/

**ASP.NET/jQuery Solution:**

If a field is declared as hidden via the ASP.NET level, then it will show up as a commented out block. To find it, use the following:

```
var hiddenField = $("<%= lblDocumentPath.ClientID %>");
```

This will find the following ASP field:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="lblDocumentPath" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't work. :/ Let me try it again.

Comment: I mean. that works in JS. But, then my code behind keeps saying the field doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: `objArgs.Item.FindControl("txtReportReference");`

objArgs is the the display grid where this input field is to be added. Funny thing is I am able to read all other columns, apart from this one.

Comment: Are you submitting this input field in a form?

Comment: Yes. Everything in that page is in a form. :/ See the edit to original question.

Comment: Looks like the solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600109/how-to-get-hiddenfield-value-in-asp-net-code-behind

Comment: 'objArgs.Item.FindControl("txtReportReference"); objArgs is the the display grid where this input field is to be added. Funny thing is I am able to read all other columns, apart from this one. ' . can u explain more?

Answer (score 0):

'visible' is not a valid html attribute. If you want to hide the element set the style attribute to "display: none;"

```
<input ID="lblDocumentPath" Class="DefaultButtons" ReadOnly="true" style="display: none"></input>
```

What is `runat='server'`? Are you trying to mix attributes of asp.net server-side controls with html controls? It will not work.

Comment: I think that might be the problem. Although I need to use this field to access on server side. And over there, normal hidden field doesn't work. I tried using 'asp:Hiddenfield' but that didn't work either. So, at this point, I am totally out of my mind. I don't know what I am doing. :(